# How to scan barcode and save the details data under the barcode in MySQL using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, barcode

I am going to develop an Inventory management system. I need to know how to get data from the scanner when I scan a barcode and save the details data of the barcode using laravel.
Example:
Barcode- 32937
Details:
quantity- 20
color- red

Comment: Use Aspose.Barcode library

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A barcode reader works like a keyboard.  So just set focus into a form input field.  If you want to make it cool then hide the field, use js to set focus into the hidden field, then use onChange to submit.